# select data from 3 tables : php

Tags: php, sql, database

I have 3 tables

```
albums: album_id, album_name, album_image, album_stock, album_price
singer: singer_id, singer_name
album_singer_mapping: singer_id, album_id
```

I want to retrieve the corresponding album name when the user enters the singer name.

I have tried using a join query as follows:

```
select a.album_name from albums a, singer s, album_singer_mapping m where m.singer_id=s.singer_id and m.album_id=a.album_id and s.singer_name like'%ankit tiwari%'
```

but it displays only 1 album name whereas there are many albums having the singer as ankit tiwari

please help! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.album_name 
from albums a 
inner join album_singer_mapping m on m.album_id = a.album_id
inner join singer s on s.singer_id = m.singer_id
where
s.singer_name like '%ankit tiwari%'
```

Comment: very good answer Mr Donal. i just give up vote for you. see my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1931001/sakthi-karthik

Comment: it still retrieves only one entry

Comment: I suspect the problem is with your data. In album_singer_mapping you should have records for each album with the same singer_id. I suspect you only have one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select albums .album_name 
  from albums 
  join album_singer_mapping on album_singer_mapping .album_id = albums .album_id
  join singer  on singer .singer_id = album_singer_mapping.singer_id
  where singer .singer_name like '%ankit tiwari%'
```